# How to verify input conforms to certain format

Tags: shell-script

I need a help on my shell script. Below is my shell script which transfers the file from one server to another.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please enter id no : "
read input_variable
echo "You entered: $input_variable"
HOST=xxxx
USER=xx
PASSWORD=xxx
ftp -inv $HOST <<EOF
user $USER $PASSWORD
cd /wpath/to/copy/files/$input_variable/inputs/final/
mput x.csv
bye
EOF
```

The shell script is working fine and it is copying the file `X.csv` once we enter id no which is present in remote server. However I have certain issues which is listed below:

1. `id` no should be of 6 characters (like `M000001`).
2. When I enter the correct id, the script is copying the file.However when I enter wrong id eg. `M000050` which is not present in remote server, then also it is showing the file is copied. But I don't have any idea where it is copying the file.
3. I need to create the directory `/final/` if it doesn't exit in remote machine. The path till inputs will be present in remote server.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. id no should be of 6 characters (like M000001).

Something like this might do that:

```
if [[ ${#input_variable} != "6" ]] then
   echo "wrong length"
   exit 1
fi
```

> 2. When I enter the correct id, the script is copying the file. However when i enter wrong id eg. M000050 which is not present in remote server, then also it is showing the file is copied. But I don't have any idea where it is copying the file.

It copies the file to the "default" `ftp` directory, because the `cd` failed, you stay in the previous directory (you can find what is the path to this directory using `pwd` command).

> 3. I need to create the directory /final/ if it doesn't exit in remote machine. the path till inputs will be present in remote server.

```
mkdir /wpath/to/copy/files/$input_variable/inputs/final/
```

should do that

Comment: thanks very helpful. Could you please let me know which is ftp directory ?

Comment: I modified the answer. `pwd` command should tell you where you are.

Comment: thanks a lot..i want to create the final directory with 777 permission. I almost tried everything..do you any suggestion?